# Dialog dismissed/hidden on Touch of Background Activity?

Tags: android, dialog, touch, custom-controls

I've noticed a troubling behavior wherein a **dialog disappears on touch of background activity screen**. Is this expected? Is there any way to suppress this behavior?

Details:
My app displays an image using a custom view control. Upon selection of a MenuItem, a dialog is displayed to change parameters of the displayed image. All works fine unless I touch on the background image, then the dialog disappears or is hidden (I can't tell which). (Note: The background activity *does* have an onTouchEvent override in place but it does nothing to overtly cause this behavior).

This is a troublesome but not a showstopper.  I have to forcibly dismiss the zombie dialog on refresh of the background, but this seems rather crude. Any suggestions or enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @DontPanic See also Sergey's answer for back button behavior

Answer (score 1):

`setCancelable(false)` will work, but it also affects behaviour of dialog on back press. Dialog will not be cancelled on back button press. If it matters you can use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`.

[Link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)).